# Why doesn't reputation carry over each Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Like for example, on Stack Overflow I have around 85 rep, but when I go to a new network site, like User Experience, my rep is reset to one, why is this?

Comment: Because you have no reputation and no experience on that specific site.

Comment: Why should it carry over? Expertise in Programming doesn't immediately translate to expertise in cooking, or aviation or chess or...

Comment: I personally think that reputation should carry over, mainly because at one reputation, you essentially have nothing except asking questions. So you carry over a certain amount so that it allows users to have some basic features that they have already earned.

Comment: @Tinfoilboy: We already have that, it is called the association bonus. If you reach 200 points on any one site you get a bonus +100 on each site you've joined or join in the future.

Comment: Do you know about the association bonus? It kicks in when you reach 200 rep on one of the sites. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's take a more dramatic example.

Stack Overflow is for programming knowledge, while the [Space Exploration Beta](https://space.stackexchange.com/) is "for spacecraft operators, scientists, engineers and enthusiasts."

Now let's say you have 20,000 reputation on Stack Overflow.  Does being a good programmer (or being able to answer programming questions well) mean that you're a good aerospace engineer and should have that reputation as well? That doesn't make much sense. You have to earn your reputation in each field.

It's not as evident with closely related Stack Exchange sites, like, say, [Unix/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), but the same principle applies.

---

To address your comment: if you just want some reputation to be carried over so that you have basic privileges, there's an "association bonus" which is explained well in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141649/202276).  Basically, you automatically get +100 reputation on any Stack Exchange site once you hit a certain level.

Comment: Yeah, now that I think about it, I'll say don't carry over ALL of your previous rep, I now think that carrying over a tiny bit, so that you can at least, for example upvote.

Comment: @Tinfoilboy Ah, well, in that case, there's an [association bonus which is explained in this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141649/202276).  :)

Comment: I would like to upvote your answer, but I have no upvote privileges. So, I'll accept it as answer, thanks for your help.